# Finding a rounded UIButton on hitTest: withEvent:

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a mapView (`GMSMapView` but it don't really matters) and above that a `UIScrollView` with a `UITableView` object as a subview.

I'm detecting where the user clicked using `hitTest: withEvent:` method of the `UIScrollView` like that:

```
//Creating "comparePoint"(CGPoint)
CGPoint comparePoint;
//Creating "screenBottom"(CGFloat) - the bottom of the scrollView (Y coordinate)
CGFloat screenBottom=CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame);
//If "allCellsHeight"(CGFloat) is smaller than 44*4 (there is less than 4 cells)
if (self.allCellsHeight<=44*4) {
    //"comparePoint""comparePoint"(CGPoint)'s Y coordinate = "point"(CGPoint)'s Y coordinate-screenBottom+"allCellsHeight" ("allCellsHeight" is the beginning height of the tableView)
    comparePoint=CGPointMake(point.x, point.y-screenBottom+self.allCellsHeight);
}else{
    //"comparePoint"(CGPoint)'s Y coordinate = "point"(CGPoint)'s Y coordinate-screenBottom+154 (154 is the beginning height of the tableView)
    comparePoint=CGPointMake(point.x, point.y-CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)+154);
}
//If "comparePoint"(CGPoint) was bigger than 0 (the user tapped on the map)
if (comparePoint.y<0) {
    return nil;
}
//If "comparePoint"(CGPoint) was smaller than 0 (the user tapped on the tableView)
return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
```

Now I've also added a button (`UIButton`) as a subview of the `UIScrollView` object and I don't have any idea how can I detect if the user taped on the button or on the mapView/tableView.

Does anybody have an idea how can I detect that?

Thank you!

Comment: y dont u add a IBAction to the method ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I do, but becuase the `hitTest: withEvent` of the `scrollView` is enabled, the tap on the button is being transfered to the map

Comment: Maybe you could give a try with the frame of your button. Then you can play around with converting point in `convertPoint:toView:` and finally check converted point with `CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect, CGPoint)`. After that you can return from `hitTest: withEvent:` your button and this will enable other events for the button, assigned in IB

Comment: @schmidt9 thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, make sure to mark my comment, if it was helpful ;)